Firebase authentication error - with App check
I am facing the error with firebase authentication when user enters wrong password it got stuck with below error message on Appcheck.

E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(18987): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.


W/LocalRequestInterceptor(18987): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.

when the above exception throws firebase exception is not showing.

Firebase auth version firebase_auth: ^5.3.3
firebase_core: ^3.8.0

